# How to show CiviCase activities in client Actions dropdown?

Tags: extension, civicase, activities

I would like to create an extension that pulls in activity types from CiviCase and allows creating those activities against a client record using the "Actions" dropdown on the Client Summary page.

If anyone has done this or similar I would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks

EDIT: The activities need to also be associated with the relevant case types (for reporting and other categorisation needs). Also, they need to be only available for a certain contact type. I'm imagining that attaching them to case types will provide a way of differentiating between them and activities that are available to all contact types.

EDIT2: I now realise this question is a product of my muddled thinking. I'll ask again when I have a clearer idea of what I actually want to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right I think this is just a config change. You just need to mark those activity types as being for Contact instead of Case, and then they appear available for use in the normal activity menu, and you can still use them for case if they are listed in the case-type config.

Comment: Actually I see the wording in the admin screens has even been changed to reflect this. When you create an activity type you can now choose from "cases only" or "contacts and cases". It used to just say contacts or cases.

Comment: Ah thanks and sorry question wasn't clear (it isn't clear in my mind to be honest). See edit